# In VB.NET, can I mark a function as deprecated?

Tags: vb.net, function, deprecated

Is there an ability in VB.NET to deprecate code?
I know that in C# there are 'attributes', and tags in java; is there anything similar in VB.NET, other than leaving a `'todo:`...?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

There are attributes in VB.NET too:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_obsolete_attribute.html

Looks like this (before your function)

```
<Obsolete("This method is deprecated, use XXXX instead.")> _
```

And since VB.NET 10 (.NET 4 and later) we [no longer need the underscore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637436.aspx).

```
<Obsolete("This method is deprecated, use XXXX instead.")>
```

Comment: You could put a whole line  
    <Obsolete("This Method is deprecated, use Method2")> Public void MethodName()

Comment: link for implicit line continuation (don't need underscore): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637436.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Use the [Obsolete] Attribute.